# Does radiative recombination occur in regular diodes as well?

Tags: led, diodes

If so then where does the photons produced go ? If not, why not ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Radiative recombination is generally not significant in silicon diodes because silicon is an *indirect bandgap* semiconductor. This means that the highest energy states in the valence band and the lowest energy states in the conduction band have different momentum, so there's no way for an electron to transfer directly from one to the other while also conserving momentum.

Recombination in silicon therefore generally involves intermediate states associated with impurities (this is called Shockley-Read-Hall recombination after three guys who first described it in the literature). Since the impurity sites are localized in space, they are spread out in momentum (due to Heisenberg's principle), and they enable the captured electron to transfer momentum to or from the crystal lattice.

Answer (score 3):

Silicon solar cells, which are actually a type of diode, do indeed emit light in the infrared spectrum when a current flows through them in forward direction. This is used as a means of characterization for these cells, because cracks, broken conductors, regions with high impurities etc. can be made visible. (Do a google image search for solar cell electroluminescense if you want to see example pictures.)